# Check if date is within the past seven days

Tags: ruby, date

I have a date in the following format: `"%d-%m-%Y"` (for example, today's date would be `07-09-2015`), and I want to see if it is within the past seven days. Can anyone recommend a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
require "date"
Date.today - 7 <= Date.parse("07-09-2015", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Gives false positives with future dates.

Answer (score 4):

sawa's answer is correct but In **rails** you can also check like this:

```
7.days.ago <= Date.parse("07-09-2015", "%d-%m-%Y")
#=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the `ago`-method without using rails, you may use only active_support:

```
require "active_support/all"
7.days.ago <= Date.parse("07-09-2015", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Or if you don't want to use any gem, then you can define it yourself:

```
require 'date'
class Fixnum

  def days
    self 
  end

  def ago
    Date.today - self
  end
end

#Executed on 2015-09-07
2.days.ago <= Date.parse("04-09-2015", "%d-%m-%Y") #=> false
2.days.ago <= Date.parse("07-09-2015", "%d-%m-%Y") #=> true
```